# trilinear map $T:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R$ unbounded implies not $C^3$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $(X, \|\cdot\|_{X})$  is a Banach space (infinite dimensional) and $$T:X\times X \times X\to X$$ is a trilinear map.

We further assume that for every $C>0$ there exist $x\in X$ such that $\|T(x,x,x)\|_{X}>C\|x\|_{X}^3.$

> Question: Can we say that $T$ is not 3-times differentiable function, that is not, $C^3$?

**Edit**: What happens if we take $X=\mathbb R$ (finite dimensional Banach space),
i.e. can we say for a trilinear map $T:\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with the property that for every $C>0$ there is $x\in \mathbb R$ such that $|T(x,x,x)|>C|x|^3$, $T$ is not $C^3$?

Any hint/comment/ references are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

For the case of $\mathbb{R}$, consider $T(x,y,z)=x\cdot y\cdot z$ which satisfies your bound, is trilinear, and smooth. For an infinite dimensional example consider $X=L^\infty([0,1])$ with $T(x,y,z)=x\cdot y \cdot z$ with multiplication understood pointwise. Again, your bound holds true, so does trilinearity, and I am pretty sure that $T$ is $k$-times Fréchet differentiable for any $k \geq 0$.